# Copy as Picture Returns Run Time Error 1004 everytime

Tags: vba, excel

I create a new excel file I create two tabs. I record a macro where I select a range of cells (Does not matter the size) on Sheet1 then select copy as picture. I then paste that image on Sheet 2. I stop the recording and delete the image and go back to Sheet 1. I then try to play the macro and i get  `Runtime Error 1004`. Does Anyone know how to fix my excel?

I am happy to share my code but did not think it was necessary sense it seems to be more a core problem in excel.

Adding Code Below.

```
Sub CopyData(tRange As String, SheetName As String)
    Worksheets(SheetName).Range(tRange).CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Call CopyData("B2:I31", "Sheet1")
End Sub
```

Adding new Details

In my office we have 4 macs. All of them had started requesting updating to excel 16.11.1 . This had been done on two mine and One other computer. Today I tried my code on one of the machines that does not have 16.11.1 and it worked. I updated to 16.11.1 and it stopped working. I feel confident that 16.11.1 is the problem.

Comment: no, it has to do with the code, please post it.

Comment: I have added the code to the original post.

Comment: @ReaganRogers Is `Sheet1` your active sheet when you run the macro?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes it is. I have tried running it while i am on that sheet and when i am on another sheet.

Comment: `Worksheets(SheetName).Range(tRange).CopyPicture xlPicture, xlPrinter`   per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.copypicture.aspx  ***although I get the 1004 if I do it that way but when I run your code as is it works fine.  I am aware that that is the interop assembly there and not https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlpictureappearance-enumeration-excel

Comment: @dwirony when i first responded to your comment it said that It was scott who asked. sorry for responding to the wrong person.

Answer (score 1):

This will accomplish what you are trying to do; set your worksheets and ranges as variables. You do not need to add the constants for `CopyPicture`  if you will be using the *defaults*, which are: `xlScreen` and `xlPicture`...

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Set Rng1 = ws1.Range("B2:I31")
Set Rng2 = ws2.Range("A1") 'change the cell ref as needed

    Rng1.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture

    ws2.Paste Destination:=Rng2

End Sub
```

Comment: Reading your update, you failed to state you were using a MAC, and had installed a new update. This is probably not a vba issue but an issue with the new update. This is not the site that can help you with operating system, program update problems. I did a search for issues with this excel update for mac, follow this hyperlink... [Go To](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/update-excel-16111-18031900-for-mac-2016-not/d31ab6f1-5c61-4583-9911-01083de581fb), you can also do searches for "excel update 16.11.1 mac" to find other links

Answer (score 0):

The Issue was caused by office being update. I followed Microsofts instructions for downgrading and it solved the issue. Thanks to all those who responded and gave support.